# I want to update my android app contents from my local server

Tags: android, django-rest-framework

I am new to android programming, my problem is i am working on android app with FAQ related to Covid-19 for communities living in a remote area with no internet connection. And i want to **update the information on the app from the local server** which is setup in one location. when users connect to the server via wifi the app should update its information from the server. And i want **the updated information to be persistent** after the update.

what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Add some code of what you have done so far!

Comment: till now my app has only hard coded text only. I haven't implemented any code so far regarding my question. and used Flutter to build the app.

Comment: Do not hard code the text. Put all text in a .txt file for instance. Then you update that file by downloading a new file from your server.

Comment: I think using database makes sense, and i thought of using json files but it can't be changed after compilation? @blackapps

Comment: You can use a json file of course. And with updating the file i ment replacing the file with the downloaded one. Then update the database. But you do not need a database if all info is in that file. Unless reading from file is too slow yes then put it in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing changes! Everything goes the same way as when fetching data form remote server, except that you just need to set your local address when creating the `connection`.

```
private static final String BASE_URL_INTERNET = "http://180.170.240.150:2045/api/";
private static final String BASE_URL_LOCAL    = "http://192.168.2.111:2045/api/"
```

All the rest goes the same way.

For the other question **updated information to be persistent after**, you need to use a `database` like SQLite.

Comment: thank you for the answer that is very helpful. Can I use django rest framework for the api?

Comment: The fact that you can connect to a local server on an Android device is independent from the framework you choose to code. So technically yes, you can use any favorite framework to code your back end. @bilubash